# Selenium WebDriver cannot locate element within an iframe, and throws NoSuchElementException

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I realise there are several queries on here for this same problem but none of them provide a solution to my particular problem.

I am running a web driver test that tries to fill out a form for a mail website to find postcodes based on address details. I keep getting this error when trying to locate the first text box:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#ctl00_BodyContent_txtBuildingNumber"}
```

I have used xpath and the id to try and locate the element but I keep getting the error. I can see that this element is present when the webdriver is running and I have been able to locate another text element on the page and enter text, but I keep getting this error for this field and other fields within the frame.

I am guessing that the problem must be to do with the fact that this field is part of an iFrame.

I have used implicit waits within the test but with no success. I still get the error.

Comment: just want to confirm this does your element change dynamically?? clear your cache and check the element if it changes its xpath..

Answer (score 12):

By the sounds of it you'll need to first switch to the `iframe` element that contains the element that you want to interact with. (Although without seeing the relevant HTML this is a bit of an extrapolated guess).

```
driver.switchTo().frame();
```

eg:

```
driver.switchTo().frame(1);
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("id")));
```

When you've finished interacting with the elements within the frame, you'll need to switch back to the main webpage.

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Comment: Thanks Mark. I am still having issues though. I used <<<driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='aspnetForm']/div[3]")));>>> and got org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"aspnetForm"}.

Comment: Could you possibly provide a html snippet for the form and its surrounding tags to make sure. Thanks.

Comment: Sure. Hope this is what you need ..</title></head>
    <body>
        

    <form name="aspnetForm" method="post" action="postcodefinder.aspx" id="aspnetForm">
<div>
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="" />

Comment: The url is http://www.royalmail.com/postcode-finder and it's the Find a postcode form.

Comment: Ah yes, at the top of the page there is an `iframe` element that bounds the form you're wanting to interact with. Try `driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("pca-iframe"));` Some people also like to assign the frame to a new instance of a `webDriver` to keep things neat but I think that's personal preference.

Comment: Brilliant!! Thanks Mark. That's better.

Answer (score 0):

Check your xpath . 
try to use simple

```
 driver.switchTo().frame(1);
```

with wait statement.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me

```
driver.switchTo().frame(myd.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='page-15']/div/p/iframe")));
```

`//*[@id='page-15']/div/p/iframe` is the xpath of the frame in which the button I was trying to click.(`driver` is of type WebDriver i.e `WebDriver driver`)
thank you

Answer (score 0):

sorry a little correction the following worked for me

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='page-15']/div/p/iframe")));
```

`//*[@id='page-15']/div/p/iframe` is the xpath of the frame in which the button i was trying to click was located. (driver is of type WebDriver i.e WebDriver driver ) thank you

Answer (score 0):

you can use wait statement and after using the wait statement use simply

driver.swithcTo().frame();

Comment: You could improve your answer by adding further explanation, code markup and documentation links.