# Selenium WebDriver: unable to locate element inside iframe using TinyMCE editor

Tags: java, selenium, iframe, selenium-webdriver

Maybe my question is similar to this [Selenium WebDriver cannot locate element within an iframe, and throws NoSuchElementException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17680022/selenium-webdriver-nosuchelementexception-unable-to-locate-element)  however I still can't find required element.
The element itself looks:

```
body id="tinymce" class="mceContentBody" contenteditable="true" onload="window.parent.tinyMCE.get('compose_295_composeEditor').onLoad.dispatch();" dir="ltr" style="overflow: auto;">
```

the `iframe` containing this element is:

```
body id="tinymce" class="mceContentBody" contenteditable="true" onload="window.parent.tinyMCE.get('compose_295_composeEditor').onLoad.dispatch();" dir="ltr" style="overflow: auto;">
```

I tried

```
driver.switchTo().frame(10);
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("tinymce")));
driver.findElement(By.id("tinymce")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.id("tinymce")).sendKeys("Privet!"); // clear mail text body
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

but received error:

```
Unable to locate frame: 10
```

Tried also something like

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("tinymce")));
```

as described in other answers there but received NoSuchElement error.

The `HTML` around the element is:

```
<div class="b-compose__editor ru_RU">
<div id="compose_295_toolbar_external" class="compose__editor_toolbar defaultSkin">
<div class="js-removeDraftContainer infobar infobar_notice infobar_draft" style="display: none;">
<div id="compose_295_composeFrame" class="b-compose__editor__frame">
<div class="compose__editor__frame_shadow"></div>
<table class="w100" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="vti w100">
<div id="compose_295_composeEditorFrame" class="composeEditorFrame" style="height: 200px;">
<table id="compose_295_shell__text" class="mlruTmpId0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="" background="" style="width: 100%">
<tbody>
<tr class="nojsdn textModeHide">
<tr>
<td class="cell w100">
<table id="compose_295_middleTable" class="w100" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr id="compose_295_middleRow_sht">
<td id="compose_295_shell__text_cell_holder" class="cell shell__text_cell_holder w100" valign="top">
<table class="w100" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr class="nojsdn textModeHide">
<tr>
<td id="compose_295_shell__text_cell" class="cell shell__text_cell w100" valign="top">
<textarea id="compose_295_composeEditor" class="bsbb composeEditor" wrap="physical" tabindex="10" name="Body" style="width: 100%; height: 570px; display: none;" cols="80" rows="15" spellcheck="true" aria-hidden="true"> </textarea>
 <span id="compose_295_composeEditor_parent" class="mceEditor defaultSkin">
 <table id="compose_295_composeEditor_tbl" class="mceLayout" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 100%; height: 570px;">
<tbody>
<tr class="mceFirst mceLast">
<td class="mceIframeContainer mceFirst mceLast">
<iframe id="compose_295_composeEditor_ifr" frameborder="0" src="javascript:""" allowtransparency="true" title="{#aria.rich_text_area}" style="width: 100%; height: 200px; display: block;" hidefocus="true" tabindex="10" scrolling="auto">
<html>
<head xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<body id="tinymce" class="mceContentBody" contenteditable="true" onload="window.parent.tinyMCE.get('compose_295_composeEditor').onLoad.dispatch();" dir="ltr" style="overflow: auto;">
</html>
</iframe>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</span>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="nojsdn textModeHide">
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
```

**UPD** [Selenium and wordpress: New post test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23999777/selenium-and-wordpress-new-post-test) , olyv's answer there helped me but:
1) It was very hard to associate that question to mine since it doesn't mention TinyMCE editor in the title and the problem isn't really with wordpress.
2) I edited my question name to indicate the problem source - TinyMCE editor.
3) Saifur's answer here answers my question perfectly.
So I believe my question shouldn't be closed

Comment: Probably the there is a duplicate id. try identifying the `iframe` with xpath or css

Comment: Are you using Firefox?

Comment: ...your element and iframe are the same element? I think you made a mistake.

Comment: how can I identify the `iframe` with selenium webdriver?

Comment: I see my element is inside the `iframe`

Comment: Yes, I'm using FireFox

Comment: Why do not you provide some `html` then?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Selenium and wordpress: New post test](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23999777/selenium-and-wordpress-new-post-test)

Comment: @SiKing It looks like you are right. I need some more time to test that but currently I must go. Hope I will do this in the nearest hours. thanks!

Comment: @SiKing it helped but I believe that my question should not be closed as I described in UPD. Thanks for the reference!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the `html` the selector to identify the `iframe` is incorrect. I am using a cssSelector that will allow you to identify the `iframe` with partial id match. Why do not you try this?

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("iframe[id$='_composeEditor_ifr']")));
d̶r̶i̶v̶e̶r̶.̶s̶w̶i̶t̶c̶h̶T̶o̶(̶)̶.̶f̶r̶a̶m̶e̶(̶d̶r̶i̶v̶e̶r̶.̶f̶i̶n̶d̶E̶l̶e̶m̶e̶n̶t̶(̶B̶y̶.̶i̶d̶(̶"̶t̶i̶n̶y̶m̶c̶e̶"̶)̶)̶)̶;̶
driver.findElement(By.id("tinymce")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.id("tinymce")).sendKeys("Privet!"); // clear mail text body
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Comment: This gives error: Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchFrameException: Element is not a frame element: BODY

Comment: Try the javascript solution provided by @Imcphers then. That's complicated

Comment: Sounds good. I forgot to remove the way you were switching the frame. thanks @aholt for noticing that

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using Firefox, try this workaround.  It does not require switching into the iFrame at all if all you want to do is submit text to the tinyMCE object.  I tried other various options that you were trying recently in Firefox, but for some reason the only one that seems reliable is this one:

```
    driver.executeScript("tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent('Privet!')");
```

Answer (score 1):

just use cssSelector with iframe

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("iframe")));
```

Comment: This will not work since TinyMCE embedded editor is used here.

Comment: Additionally, there are multiple ifarmes on that pages. Editor is 10-th frame while your code will select the first iframe on the page.